# Verb for "just opening a bit" a window or door

Tags: word-request

Is there a single verb that conveys the idea of "just opening X a bit", "slightly opening" or "opening a gap"?

**Examples**

- He ____ the window just so that a light breeze could come in.
- The door was not totally closed. Someone had ____ it.

**Remark**

The option that I like the most so far is "tilt", but I see two drawbacks:

- It conveys a vertical movement (it wouldn't apply to a door).
- It could, especially to the eyes of non-fluent speakers, not be clear if the window/door is being opened or just its inclination is being changed.

Comment: **Tilt** sounds very wrong to this native US English speaker.  "Tilt" means something like "put at a sideways angle".  You could open a window by tilting it *if* it opened that way, but if it opened by sliding, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Related: How should I understand “She cracked open a door”? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58611/how-should-i-understand-she-cracked-open-a-door

Comment: According to Green’s Dictionary of Slang, to crack meaning to  open has an old history: ***crack***  [late 16C+] to open, orig. of a bottle etc, meaning to have a drink; latterly to open anything, e.g. a door etc. - https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/stfhfzq

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**[Crack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crack)**

- to open a small amount

> crack a window

---

> He cracked the window just so that a light breeze could come in.
>
> The door was not totally closed. Someone had cracked it open.

---

Per comments below, if you are in North America, saying "he cracked the window" is perfectly acceptable.

But in other places, saying *he opened the window a crack* or *he cracked the window open* would be clearer.

Comment: "Crack a window" to me sounds like you've broken it! I would however say "He opened the window a crack".

Comment: @Muzer This seems to be an Americanism. I can't find anything similar to this in the English OED. There is the more usual noun version: `the door opened a tiny crack` and the phrase `crack (open) a bottle` but that's it. Edit: On the other hand the US version of the OED does list the meaning as does merriam-webster. Sounds weird to my ears too.

Comment: @Voo that would make sense, since I'm British :)

Comment: As an American, "crack the window" sounds fine and was my first thought.

Comment: @Muzer Same here (well not exactly British, but I did learn BE originally). I'd be pretty worried if someone told me they cracked the window.

Comment: I usually hear it as "cracked **open** a window/door".  "Cracked a window" would be ambiguous between "cracked open" and "broke"

Comment: As another American, I have never heard "crack the window", but maybe "crack open the window" and "open the window a crack" as Muzer commented.

Comment: @BlueRaja - In isolation, the phrase "I cracked the window" might be ambiguous. In context, the sentence "He cracked the window so a light breeze could come in" is pretty clear.

Comment: @Muzer - From [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/crack): **crack** (*verb*) To open to a slight extent : _cracked the window to let in some air_. Interesting that this might be a North American regionalism.

Comment: To this speaker of NYC American English, "crack a window" sounds perfectly natural.  "Crack *open* a window" sounds weird, like the speaker was not quite familiar with the idiom.  "Crack the window" does not seem ambiguous to me unless there is *no* context - hearing "he crossed the room and cracked the window", I would always think that he opened the window, not that he broke the glass.

Comment: Here's something that suggests that the *crack the window* idiom is relatively new - notice that it doesn't even really begin to take off until 1970, and "crack *open* the window" doesn't really take off until 1990 or so: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cracked+the+window%2Ccracked+open+the+window&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccracked%20the%20window%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccracked%20open%20the%20window%3B%2Cc0

Comment: To introduce yet another formulation (Southern California childhood, Washington DC adulthood), I would *crack the window open*; *crack the window* would be adequate in context, but I agree with @stangdon that *crack open the window* sounds odd to me for no firm reason. I would *crack open* a beer, not a window.

Comment: I'm from California and while this usage is familiar to me, I agree that it's probably an Americanism and possibly even a regionalism. It's also worth noting that it's used for doors too, not just windows.

Comment: @stangdon The ngram search also shows that "cracked the window" is five times more common in American English than it is in British English.

Comment: "crack a window"  is idiomatic for me, as a Canadian.

Comment: Wow! Controversial. My immediate thought was "there have to be better ways to open a window than to break it" How many Melville, Twain, Hemingway, Steinbeck, Pynchon books have I misunderstood because of it?!

Comment: Native BrE speaker here, who immediately though "crack a window" and would be perfectly happy with it. I am, however, still relatively young (early 30s) and watch a lot of US TV, so I may have picked up the phrase from there.

Comment: Common in the South too; I hear it here in Alabama all the time.

Comment: British speaker here and _"Crack a window"_ would sound fine in context. Perhaps _"Crack a window ajar"_ would help clarify. Not to be confused with _"Crack a window with a jar"_...

Comment: @PatrickT It is quite possible the modern usage did not have much weight at the time those authors were writing - a comment above indicates this took off in the 1970's.  I don't think it's very likely that there would have been confusion, particularly from such skilled authors.

Comment: @Muzer In British English I would also use "unlatched" as the verb, as in "He unlatched the window so it opened a crack."

Comment: Another Brit here: "crack open" would be good "crack" alone suggests breakage primarily, though would be understood after a pause or in context.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft For me (Midwestern/Californian) it depends on context and, somewhat, on the determiner. "He cracked a window" without further context is ambiguous, but "He cracked *the* window" leans towards opening over breaking for some reason while "He cracked *my* window" strongly implies breakage. In the imperative, though, the expression pretty clearly refers to "opening a little bit" without needing any further context. Something like "Hey, could you crack a window?" isn't ambiguous for me at all.

Comment: Don't say "crack" as in "opened slightly." It's rarely used, and a lot of people won't understand it. Just say "opened slightly" instead. It's simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 19):

Though not exactly a verb, the adjective/adverb [**ajar**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ajar) was the first thing that came to my mind when I saw your post:

> If a door, window or other opening is ajar, it is slightly open.

For example:

> We **left** the door **ajar** so that we could hear what they were saying.

You can easily turn it into a verb expression if you use it along with an appropriate verb: **set something ajar** or **leave something ajar**. Thanks TRiG in the comments section for this suggestion.

Comment: If you want a verb, try *set ajar*.

Comment: It's time someone came up with "He ajared the window to let the breeze in"

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, Michael. I think @rosslh's answer fits more my needs, so I marked it as the official answer, but _ajar_ is an interesting fancy word to add to my vocabulary ;)

Comment: @guest_user - There is a difference between "open something slightly" and "not close something completely". For your first example sentence rosslh's answer is perfect: "He *cracked* the window just so that a light breeze could come in.". This really doesn't work for your second example, as you imply that it had been fully opened and then later partially closed; for that this answer is much more idiomatic: "The door was not totally closed. Someone had *left it ajar*."

Comment: A famous preserve producer has died and in his will he left his favorite door a jar. (I'll get my coat).

Comment: @AndyT I've heard "left open a crack / left cracked open / left cracked" many times. In person, in books, in television and movies.

Comment: @Aethenosity - Yep, those phrases all work. I think my *main* point still stands: the verb "to crack" means "to open something a small amount" and can't mean "to close something but not completely". For the closing you need the verb "to leave" with an adjective / past-participle. The secondary point of the choice of adjective: I agree with you that it can be "ajar" or "cracked open".

Comment: In the US early days of cars that "talked to you", when you didn't get a car door completely closed (and latched), the car's voice would say, "Your door is ajar", and my friends and I would always say back (to the car), "No, my door is a door. It's just not latched." lol

Comment: @geneSummons When is a door not a door? WHEN IT'S AJAR!

Answer (score 4):

**Nudge**

*He nudged the door open.*

*Would you nudge that window open?*

Answer (score 3):

## Pull it to/Close it to

is a perhaps rare, maybe regional way of saying "Close the door so that it's resting to the frame, but not shut all the way". As in "Pull it to [the frame]". Leaving it on the latch is this, also. I heard this expression in Yorkshire as a kid in the noughties, but it has apparently been [heard elsewhere](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/58/messages/1871.html).

This is mainly for doors, for windows I'd use the American sounding "crack" as above.

Answer (score 2):

### to prop (open)

Merriam Webster: [Definition 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prop)

I agree that crack is better, but this was my first thought. Implies the use of a helper object like a doorstop.

> - He *propped* the window *open* so that a light breeze could come in.
> - The door was not totally closed. Someone had *propped* it *open*.

In my opinion, really couldn't be used without 'open.' <strike>or at least another adjective, like (possibly) 'ajar.'</strike> (I can't think of an example that sentence that sounds good and uses only 'ajar.')

Comment: But *prop* doesn't say anything about how open the window/door is. I can prop a window or door open all the way, and that's not what OP wants.